# How can I smooth a set of discrete data points for the purpose of schedule planning?

Tags: discrete-data, smoothing, filter

Disclaimer: I do not have a background in statistics or the math behind filtering, save one long-time-ago college course.

I have a well defined problem space. I am calculating hourly staffing requirements for retail stores.

The raw values are based on a matrix of the full-time employees required for a given historical transaction volume. The calculation process generates a set of ordered pairs ( hour, people ) for a given store and day.

The output of this process can produce single hour periods where the number of people required are much higher or much lower than the neighboring range, but the concern is only the lower values.

So if the calculated data  (hour, people) for a given store and day were to be:

```
8, 2   -> I need two people to work from 8a - 9a
9, 3   -> I need three people to work from 9a - 10a, etc.
10, 3
11, 2
12, 3
13, 3
14, 1
15, 3
16, 3
...
```

I need a filtering approach to: turn (11,2) into (11,3) and turn (14,1) into (14,3) 
I would never want an outputted value to result in a lower value than the source data.

**EDIT - Additional Information ** 
The practical need for this data and the smoothing process is for a application user interface. The store managers schedule their staff for a given week using this data as a guide. The raw data represents the minimum staff coverage for each hour. When store manager builds their schedule, the application flags time periods where insufficient coverage is detected, i.e. below the calculated minimum staff coverage.

Schedules are built up based on shifts, which means it is impractical to have someone work 2 hours, take an hour off, then work another 2 hours. We would want that person to work the entire 5 hours. We want to modify the raw data in such a way as to avoid having these coverage spikes as shown in the example above.

Comment: What is the "filtering" supposed to do? How would you interpret its results?

Comment: I added some clarifying details above. I know I am out of my depth here, so if I can add more detail about the problem, please let me know.